# Tomcat server, stuck at "INFO : server startup in t ms"

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

[image]I am using Eclipse Indigo with 'apache-tomcat-6.0.32' for Java development. When is started it for a couple of times, it started and worked fine. i start the tomcat with '*startup.bat'* placed in the bin folder. But after some time, it started giving error on console. the main 2 errors worth mentioning are.

1 - could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout

2 - could not instantiate appender named stdout

Then in the end it says, INFO : server startup in 24329 ms and it never start afterwards.

I figured out 4 files with the same name *log4j.properties* ... 2 files are in the eclipse folder.. The other 2 files are in

E:\Workspace\rmbl-parent\prefs2-rmbl\src

the contents are

```
>log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE

>(hash)log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

>(hash) CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
>log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
>log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

>(hash) LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=mbk.log
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=INFO
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - = %m%n
```

and

E:\Workspace\rmbl-parent\mobiliser-rmbl\src\test\resources

and the contents are

```
>log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

>(hash)log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=debug
>log4j.logger.net.paybox=trace
>(hash)log4j.logger.net.paybox.util.SqlHelper=info
>log4j.logger.net.paybox.util.prefs=debug
>(hash)log4j.logger.net.paybox.aaa.scheduler=info
>log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=all
>log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=fatal
>log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cfg=fatal

>log4j.logger.net.paybox.mobiliser.money.jbpm=trace

>log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%-25.25t] (%-30.30F:%L)\t- %m%n
```

so, which one should i modify?

P.S all the environmental variables are set. i am trying to configure maven alongside it and i am failing in that as well. 
Kindly anyone with a solution, please let me know

Comment: Where is your  log4j.properties file located?

Comment: i searched my laptop and the internet as well to get the default location, but i was unable to find this file on my hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `log4j.properties` file and place it in the class path (`src/main/resources` in case of maven)

**Example:**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**Refs:**

1. [log4j - Configuration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm)
2. [Log4j.Properties Example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)
3. [Apache Logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: i have updated my question and provided the 2 log files(out of 4). please have a look at it.

Comment: Are you using maven? Do you have a src/main/resources in project? If so place the file at E:\Workspace\rmbl-parent\prefs2-rmbl\src in src/main/resources and modify it.

Comment: as far as Maven is concern, i have all the maven variable set in environmental variables. Maven's folder is placed in the root alongside my workspace folder. I m not pretty much sure if Maven is integrated or not...
and i did exactly what u advised, but the status and error remains the same.

Comment: i have attached the console image with it to give a clear picture